# How to turn on and off push notification using firebase subscribeToTopic('topic') and unsubscribeFromTopic in flutter and how to give topic

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to on and off push notification using  `await  FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('topic')` from where I get this topic using flutter and sql database and use messaging for firebase messaging.
`FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('topic')` this is not working for me.

When I turn on push notification then `FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('topic')` and then send notification to this user and when I turn off notification `FirebaseMessaging.instance.unsubscribeFromTopic('topic')` and stop this push notification.

Answer (score 1):

You can call this code where ever the user changes notification prefrence.

```
// Get the topic from your SQL database
bool userHasOptedIn = ... // retrieve the user's notification prefrence
String topic = 'your_topic';

if (userHasOptedIn) {
  // Subscribe the user to the topic
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic(topic);
} else {

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.unsubscribeFromTopic(topic);
}
```

I hope, it helps you.

happy coding...

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I tried this, but this is not working for me. I took topic from sql database. I can't understand what is the problem.

Comment: welcome dear. by the way please share more detail and please put your code to see what is happening.